# How to call a php file with arguments from VBA for Mac? Equivalent of VBA.createObject("wscript.shell") on Mac?

Tags: php, excel, vba, macos, arguments

**Still in need of help :)**

I'm trying to adapt the following chunk of code to VBA for Mac (as the final implementation *has* to be on Mac):

```
Dim ws as Object
Dim result as String
Set ws = VBA.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
cd = "php " & dirPHP & "\verificar.php " & FileName
result = ws.Run(cd)
Set ws = Nothing
```

It runs perfectly on Windows, but when trying to adapt it for Mac I'm encountering many problems.

What I am basically doing on the previous chunk is calling a PHP file that takes the first argument (in this case, `FileName`) and calls the verify function, returning some values.

The thing is that there are some posts explaining how to do this, but I have seen no examples on how to do it for PHP, and especially for PHP passing an input argument.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. `result = AppleScriptTask("PHPCommand.applescript", "PHPCommandHandler", FileName)`
2. `e = "php " & dirPHP & "/verificar.php " & FileName cd = "do shell script """ & e & """" result = MacScript(cd)`

(On the Mac Terminal I am able to run the PHP file fine, with the resulting "e" string).

3. And some other fruitless things, like the shell() function, or some other user-defined functions (I saw someone defined a "system()" function). I also tried many ways of putting the double and simple quotes, and simplified the path to the PHP file (dirPHP) and the path + filename of the argument (FileName) by removing all blank spaces and thus the need of using additional quotes.

Please help me! I'd be really grateful, as yesterday I spent the whole day on this and I can't keep wasting time on something that is so simple on Windows... But I have to do it on Mac.

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the VBA `Shell` function.

> **`Shell`**
>
> Runs an executable program and returns a Variant (Double) representing
> the program's task ID if successful; otherwise, it returns zero.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `Shell(pathname, [ windowstyle ])`

Comment: But what is pathname, the entire command or just the path to the PHP file? What I need is to run a command that looks like this: "php path/to/PHPfile/nameOfPHPfile.php path/to/argumentFile/FileName". When I run that command (pathname = command) on VBA, it says "path not found". Any further ideas? :)

Comment: Well you need to learn Macintosh standards.

Comment: That's what I'm trying, but since it's a challenge for me I was asking for help. But thanks for dropping by!

Comment: You would get that same error on my Windows' computer, your computer has been modified by you which is why it works for you.. You are not specifying fully qualified pathnames especially to php.exe.

Comment: Oh okay, that could be it! It's true I modified some paths when I installed PHP on my Windows. I didn't modify anything on Mac, as PHP was already installed.
But on the Mac Terminal it runs well, which is something I find weird!!